# Unnecessary label on continue/break

Tags: java, loops

I have confuse of execution the next code :

```
        label:
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) continue;
            if (i == 99) {
                continue label;
            }
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
        }
```

I was hope that this cycle is infinite. But no. When value is **99** - programm was exit. I try to play with `continue` and `break` operators but still haven't expected result.

I just try understand why this cycle is not infinite and what i gonna do to make it?

Output :

```
i = 1
i = 3
......
i = 93
i = 95
i = 97

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I guess you should read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html, especially the _"The continue Statement"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` *continues* the labelled loop, which does not involve resetting `i` to its initial value; so nothing you're doing prevents `i` from increasing, until it reaches `100` and the loop terminates. And yes, you're correct that the label is unnecessary.

To make it infinite, just reset `i` within the loop, no need for a label or `continue`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i == 99) {
        i = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("i = " + i);
}
```

or perhaps this, which outputs 99 then 0 again and keeps going:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    System.out.println("i = " + i);
    if (i == 99) {
        i = -1;
    }
}
```

Or if for some reason you really, really wanted to do this with `continue`, you'd want a second outer loop: http://ideone.com/ofgpK3

```
label:
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        if (i == 99) {
            continue label;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for nice explantation! I will accept your answer at 6 minutes. Stackoverflow don't allow me this now.

Answer (score 1):

A label is nothing like a *goto* instruction with what you seem to confuse it with. When you `continue` a program flow to a labeled loop instruction, you only `continue` its execution by executing its next loop. When you continue at `i = 99`, you only execute the `for` loop with the next iteration value `i = 100` what renders the loop's condition `i < 100` to be `false` such that the loop terminates.

What you are trying to achieve would require an outer loop such that:

```
label: while (true) {
  for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) continue;
      if (i == 99) {
        continue label;
       }
       System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I removed the condition within the `for` loop which is now redundant because the explicit *jump* back into the outer `while` loop what implicitly causes the inner loop to terminate. This jump restarts the inner loop and therefore causes the counter to reset to `i = 0`. In general, such explicit program flow is however difficult to read and easy to confuse such that one should avoid it whenever possible for the same reason as one would want to avoid a *goto statement* of which labels are very lightweight versions of.

Answer (score 0):

You are continuing with your for loop (And not printing out the number) every time `(i % 2 == 0)` or if `(i == 99)` are true. But when i reaches 99, your condition `i < 100` is reached and the loop exits.

For an easier infinite loop, use

```
while(true) {
    //Your code
}
```

or

```
for(;;) {
    //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` initialized only once. `continue` doesn't reset `i` to 0, so when you reach `continue` label, the condition in the `for` loop will be evaluated to `false`, and you'll skip it.

See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> - The initialization expression initializes the loop; **it's executed
>     once, as the loop begins**.
> - When the termination expression evaluates to
>     false, the loop terminates.
> - The increment expression is invoked after
>     each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this
>     expression to increment or decrement a value.